# desactivate specific plugin stylesheet in Symfony 1.4

Tags: plugins, symfony1, stylesheet, apostrophe

I would like to desactivate one stylesheet of apostrophePlugin 1.4 to be able to overide it with my own definitions.

Do you have any tips to desactivate or at least make it loading last?

I read something about view.yml, where I could write:

```
default:
  stylesheets:
    - a.css: {position : last}
```

But I don't know how to get a.css inside plugin folder...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Find a module in plugin where you want do exclude css
2. Override it's `config` dir with `view.yml`
3. Override `view.yml`